# Deployment Issue

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I'm trying to host a website i'm getting an error regarding assemblies.I have added the assemblies to the bin folder also.Fllowing is the error page

http://d3430264.u711.laknetwork.com/real/login.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a version related issue. You may have dropped a dll into bin but it's version does not match with the expected one.

You can edit the AssemblyInfo.cs to have the version tag as this `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]` . And then clean the solution and redeploy

Comment: Where can i find the AssemblyInfo.cs file.My application works fine in local host

Comment: Well, if you have the source, you could find it under project's Properties folder

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, before publishing, select the reference and open its properties window. See if there you have option copy to local. It sounds the assembly resides in GAC and is not available while deployment. Or you can copy paste the same version assmbly in target machine in System32 directory or local bin and register using regasm /tlb (managed dll) , regsvr32 (unmanaged).